# Question about conditional expectation on finite space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X_i$'s are Bernoulli random variables with success probability $p_i$ and $f$ is a function of $X_1,...,X_n$. Is that true $E[f\mid X_1,\dots,X_n]=\mathbf{1}_{\{X_n=1\}}E[f\mid X_1,\dots,X_n=1]+\mathbf{1}_{\{X_n=0\}}E[f\mid X_0,\dots,X_n=0]$ and
 
$E[f\mid X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}]=p_i E[f\mid X_1,\dots,X_n=1]+(1-p_i)E[f\mid X_1,\dots, X_n=0]$? 
I think both are correct but not sure how to check the requirement that if $Y=E[X\mid\mathcal{F}]$, then $\int_AYdP=\int_A XdP$ for all $A\in \mathcal{F}$.
Revision: we assume $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent.

Comment: Isn't it just the total expectation formula?

Comment: In going to the second equation, are you implicitly assuming the $\{X_i\}$ are mutually independent?  For example, what if $X_1=X_2$?

Comment: Yes, we have the assumption that $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent.

Comment: It is defined in some advanced language, but I think these notations are coordinated.

Comment: It looks like the first equation is true in general, and the second follows by integrating out the $X_n$ and using independence (it would not be true without independence).

Comment: How to define $E(X\mid Y,A)$ in general, when $(X,Y)$ are random variables and $A$ is an event?

Answer (score -2):

*Yees*, if you mix the notation for expectation conditioned by a random variable with the notation for expectation conditioned by an event, which are confusingly too similar in appearance.

Otherwise, for a sequence of Bernoulli random variables, then indeed:

$$\bbox[1ex,lemonchiffon]{\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots,X_n)~{=~ {\mathbf 1_{X_n=1}\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},\mathbf 1_{X_n=1}) }+{ \mathbf 1_{X_n=0}\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},\mathbf 1_{X_n=0}) } } }$$

And since $\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots, X_{n-1})=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots,X_n)\mid X_1,\ldots, X_{n-1})$ and also $\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X_n=1}\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})\overset{(1)}=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X_n=1})\overset{(2)}=p_i$ (only if (1) *mutually independent* and (2) *identically distributed*) then too:

$$\bbox[1ex,lemonchiffon]{\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})~{=~{ p_i~\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},\mathbf 1_{X_n=1})} + {(1-p_i)~\mathsf E(f\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},\mathbf 1_{X_n=0})}}}$$

Comment: Something funky happened in your last equation, the left-hand-side is a random variable that depends on $(X_1, ..., X_{n-1})$ while the right still seems to have dependence on $X_n$ via the indicator $1_{\{X_n=1\}}$.

Comment: ps: I didn't downvote.

Comment: LoTE $E(Z\mid L)~{= E(E(Z\mid L,X)\mid L) \\= pE(X\mid L,\mathbf 1_{X=1})+(1-p)E(Z\mid L,\mathbf 1_{X=0})}$ where $p=P(X=1\mid L)$

Comment: Note that $1_{\{X=1\}}$ is a random variable (we have $X=1_{\{X=1\}}$ if $X$ is Bernoulli).  The random variable $1_{\{X=1\}}$ is distinct from the event $\{X=1\}$. An example to illustrate that the last yellow equation is not quite right is $n=2$, $X_1, X_2$ iid Bernoulli $P[X_1=1]=P[X_2=1]=1/2$, $f=X_1X_2$.  Then $E[X_1X_2|X_1]=(1/2)X_1$, but $(1/2)E[X_1X_2|X_1,X_2]+(1/2)E[X_1X_2|X_1,X_2]=X_1X_2$.  One depends on $X_2$, the other does not. Note also that $X_2$ and $1-X_2$ generate the same sigma algebras, so conditioning on $1-X_2$ is equivalent to conditioning on $X_2$.